# XML node from nodelist is not reading current loop values_ Resolved

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to loop through an Xml file and display the value for type in a message.But my code is repeatedly giving he first record values.

**Below is my XML**

```
<Request deploymentMode="test">
  <ConfirmationRequest>
    <ConfirmationHeader noticeDate="2019-10-03T01:53:54+0200" type="accept" operation="new" confirmID="0002933085">...</ConfirmationHeader>
    <OrderReference orderID="50084">...</OrderReference>
    <ConfirmationItem lineNumber="000010" quantity="16.000">
      <UnitOfMeasure>CT</UnitOfMeasure>
      <ConfirmationStatus type="rejected" quantity="16.000">
        <UnitOfMeasure>CT</UnitOfMeasure>
        <Comments>ConfirmedQuantity:0.000</Comments>
        <Comments>reject reason: EDI 855 Rejected: Out of Stock</Comments>
      </ConfirmationStatus>
    </ConfirmationItem>
    <ConfirmationItem lineNumber="000020" quantity="144.000">
      <UnitOfMeasure>CT</UnitOfMeasure>
      <ConfirmationStatus deliveryDate="2019-10-02T07:00:00+0200" type="accepted" quantity="144.000">
        <UnitOfMeasure>CT</UnitOfMeasure>
        <Comments>ConfirmedQuantity:144.000</Comments>
      </ConfirmationStatus>
    </ConfirmationItem>
    <ConfirmationItem lineNumber="000030" quantity="45.000">
      <UnitOfMeasure>CT</UnitOfMeasure>
      <ConfirmationStatus deliveryDate="2019-10-02T07:00:00+0200" type="partial-accept" quantity="45.000">
        <UnitOfMeasure>CT</UnitOfMeasure>
        <Comments>ConfirmedQuantity:45.000</Comments>
        <Comments>Partial Accept reason -Out of Stock etc.</Comments>
      </ConfirmationStatus>
    </ConfirmationItem>
    <ConfirmationItem lineNumber="000040" quantity="65.000">
      <UnitOfMeasure>CT</UnitOfMeasure>
      <ConfirmationStatus deliveryDate="2019-10-02T07:00:00+0200" type="accepted" quantity="65.000">
        <UnitOfMeasure>CT</UnitOfMeasure>
        <Comments>ConfirmedQuantity:65.000</Comments>
      </ConfirmationStatus>
    </ConfirmationItem>
  </ConfirmationRequest>
</Request>
```

**My Code is as below.**

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ConfirmationRequest/ConfirmationItem");

                    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                    {
                     OrderNumber = null;
                        LineNumber = 0;
                        Quantity = 0;
                        UnitOfMeasure = null;
                        DeliveryDate = null;
                        Type = null;
                        ConfirmationStatus_Quantity = 0;
                        ConfirmationStatus_Unitofmeasure = null;
                        LineitemComments_1 = null;
                        LineitemComments_2 = null;
                        LineitemComments_3 = null;
                        LineitemComments_4 = null;
                        LineitemComments_5 = null;
                        CreatedDate = null;

                        XmlNode orh = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Request/ConfirmationRequest/OrderReference");
                        OrderNumber = (orh.Attributes["orderID"].Value == null) ? null : orh.Attributes["orderID"].Value;
                        LineNumber = int.Parse(xn.Attributes[0].Value == null ? null : xn.Attributes[0].Value);
                        Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(xn.Attributes[1].Value == null ? null : xn.Attributes[1].Value);
                        UnitOfMeasure = xn.SelectSingleNode("UnitOfMeasure").InnerText == null ? null : xn.SelectSingleNode("UnitOfMeasure").InnerText;
                        DeliveryDate = xn.SelectSingleNode("//Request/ConfirmationRequest/ConfirmationItem/ConfirmationStatus/@deliveryDate").InnerText == null ? null : xn.SelectSingleNode("//Request/ConfirmationRequest/ConfirmationItem/ConfirmationStatus/@deliveryDate").InnerText;
                        DeliveryDate = DeliveryDate.Substring(0, 10);
                        Type = xn.SelectSingleNode("//Request/ConfirmationRequest/ConfirmationItem/ConfirmationStatus/@type").InnerText == null ? null : xn.SelectSingleNode("//Request/ConfirmationRequest/ConfirmationItem/ConfirmationStatus/@type").InnerText;

                    }
```

In every iteration , i am getting almost all the values except the

1. ConfirmationStatus tag's attribute string DeliveryDate.
2. ConfirmationStatus tag's attribute string Type.

Delivery date and **Type** are not changing with every iteration.

Every loop i get below results.

**Loop -1 :** DeliveryDate : 2019-10-02T07:00:00+0200  , Type = rejected.
 
**Loop -2 :** DeliveryDate : 2019-10-02T07:00:00+0200  , Type = rejected. 
 
**Loop -3 :** DeliveryDate : 2019-10-02T07:00:00+0200  , Type = rejected. 
 
**Loop -4 :** DeliveryDate : 2019-10-02T07:00:00+0200  , Type = rejected.

Where you can see these values of type are different for each loop and there is no deliverydate for loop-1.

I looked around related solutions , couldn't find any.

**ANSWER**

Figured out where exactly i am making a mistake.

**I should be using**

```
**xn.SelectSingleNode("ConfirmationStatus/@deliveryDate").InnerText**
**xn.SelectSingleNode("ConfirmationStatus/@type").InnerText**
```

**Instead of**

```
xn.SelectSingleNode("//Request/ConfirmationRequest/ConfirmationItem/ConfirmationStatus/@deliveryDate").InnerText
xn.SelectSingleNode("//Request/ConfirmationRequest/ConfirmationItem/ConfirmationStatus/@type").InnerText
```

Above statement always goes to the first occurance , hence i am only getting same values. **

Not sure if i am making a mistake somewhere.

Pls suggest.

Thnks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml serialization :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));
            Request request = (Request)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public class Request
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string deploymentMode { get; set; }

        public ConfirmationRequest ConfirmationRequest { get; set; } 
    }
    public class ConfirmationRequest
    {
        public ConfirmationHeader ConfirmationHeader { get; set; }
        public OrderReference OrderReference { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public List<ConfirmationItem> ConfirmationItem { get; set; }
    }
    public class ConfirmationHeader
    {
        private DateTime _noticeDate { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string noticeDate {
            get { return _noticeDate.ToString(); }
            set { _noticeDate = DateTime.Parse(value); } 
        }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string opertion { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string confirmID { get; set; }


    }
    public class OrderReference
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string orderID { get; set; }

        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    public class ConfirmationItem
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string lineNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public decimal quantity { get; set; }
        public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
        public ConfirmationStatus ConfirmationStatus { get; set; } 
    }
    public class ConfirmationStatus
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public decimal quantity { get; set; }
        public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public string[] Comments { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. Will check and get back to u.

Comment: Xmlreader.Create is not reading any data from my XML. reader {None}. Am i missing something ?. Pls advise.

Comment: Code is working with your posted xml.  Make sure the filename is correct.

Comment: Tried the same , no use @jsweng.  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(FILENAME)) - No data being read

Comment: Any exceptions?  If you are reading a string than use : new StringReader(string).  You should have at least the root class Request.  With Serializer library if you do not get the root class that you get an exception.

Comment: Yea, Works fine. Thank you. However, i have found the root cause of the issue and Resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks JD , Appreciate your prompt help.